# background-color not working css

Tags: css

I have a Div tag in aspx page

```
<div id="mainDiv">
...........                                
</div>
```

Following style is working for it all right except `background-color`. Any changes made in following class also work. `background-color`is also applied at design time in visual-studio but does not work at run-time. Any reasons?

```
#mainDiv
{
    width:95%;
    background-color:Silver;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:Maroon;    
}
```

**Update** Instead of `background-color:Silver;`, I have tried `background-color:Silver !important;`but no difference. However changing `color:Maroon;` to `color:Blue;` affects

**Edit** I have no other css files for this page only one css file is linked to it

**Edit** I had two divs inside the `mainDiv` there style was `float:left` when I removed `float:left` I was able to see the changes in `background-color` of `mainDiv`. Still do not know the reason

Comment: Any chance you have conflicting style rules for 'div' or something else like that? When you look at the inspector for "Matched CSS Rules," what does it say for background-color?

Comment: Write background-color:Silver !important; if it works then you have conflicting rules

Comment: It also works for me at design time but looking for some hell reason, why it is not working at run-time. I mentioned that i have it in aspx page

Comment: @Sami can u create a jsfiddle.net link and show us than i help u .....

Comment: @RohitAzad. Sorry I have it in aspx page

Comment: Please look at the CSS styles in the "Matched CSS Rules" inspector in IE or Chrome: http://robpaveza.net/pub/divcss.png for an example.  Is your background-color: Silver rule crossed out for some reason?

Comment: @Sami used to this css     body #mainDiv{background-color:silver;}

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> Edit: I had two divs inside the mainDiv there style was float:left
> when I removed float:left I was able to see the changes in
> background-color of mainDiv. Still do not know the reason

Then it's clear: If your only contents are floated elements, the element's height remains zero and it's therefore invisible, because there is no "normal" content and floated elements can go out of an element.

To avoid that, add `overflow: auto;` to your `#mainDiv` rule. This will cause the floats to be included/wrapped by the their parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Silver` try using Hexadecimal Color Codes

```
background-color:#C0C0C0;
```

Comment: Unlikely to be the culprit.  HTML 4.01 defined this color name as one of the first sixteen basic colors.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names

Comment: No difference. Using Silver is correct as well. But can not understand what there can be some other reason.

Comment: @Sami try setting `!important` like this `background-color:Silver !important;`

Answer (score 0):

There may be some conflict wiith other CSS on that page as this works fine:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    content here
</div>
```

CSS

```
#mainDiv {     
    width:95%;     
    background-color:Silver;     
    font-weight:bold;     
    color:Maroon;     
}
```

See here: **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qUyp2/93/)**